# node-gyp rebuild fails on Mac OS High Sierra while npm install

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

I am getting following error in the terminal, while it tries to install one of package "node-expat". I have tried switching to different node version using nvm but still it is failing with same error.

```
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-expat
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-expat@2.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.0.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\<redacted>\npm-debug.log
```

I went ahead installing x-code as suggested on git hub page, on my machine and then it is giving following error,. Not sure how to debug further.

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, 
but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

Answer (score 6):

I just got it fixed on my machine and my fellow colleagues machine.

**Followed the following steps to fix it on MacOS highSierra 10.13:**

1. Downloaded command line tools (MacOS 10.13) for xcode and installed it.
   Download it from "https://developer.apple.com/download/more/"
2. Installed xcode 10.0 from the app store. Opened xcode and went through the regular configuration xcode does in the initial start up.
3. After this it started giving "xcode-select" path issue as stated in the description  above. On running command "**xcode-select --print-path**" it was showing path as  '/ Library/Developer/CommandLineTools', so i went ahead and tried "**xcode-select --reset**" after which the path changed to "**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer**". 
   Immediately after it the build started working without any issues.

Answer (score 3):

Solution above mentioned by Luke worked partially for me (MacOS) but created another issue :
`gyp ERR! stack Error:`make`failed with exit code: 2` which was solved by removing locked json file. Issue was created due to permission in MAC OS. So if you have xcode re-installed already,  open terminal (command line) and type:

```
xcode-select --reset
```

then go to your project folder and remove:
 **package-lock.json**
Now in terminal reinstall project :

```
npm install
```

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: My suggestion was my case (it happened to me and was solved as explained above). So it's not a guess.  Please leave comment is you are to leave negative vote so I know why you are doing it and remove my comment if you there is a reason for it. Otherwise this way we are misleading someone who might have exact case as mine was.